# Error obtaining UI hierarchy and Screen not available

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-emulator, view-hierarchy

I use Android Device Monitor to check my Android App view hierarchy.

Run the app in android studio's device simulator.

[image]

Open the Android Device Monitor.

[image]

Then choose my App and Dump View Hierarchy for UI Automator, but I get this,

[image]

I also try to Screen Capture the App, and I get this,

[image]

Android studio 2.3.3 on Mac OS Sierra v10.12.5

Comment: I think you need to click on the device first in the list

Comment: @cricket_007 I have try that, but without success. I have a webview in my app with dynamic contetn, and a ijkplayer to play the live demo.

Comment: I don't think any WebView is the problem. Try to create a MCVE to verify